# Has anyone experience with new deploys on Heroku crashing, after building a new local directory to house the app locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I recently have cloned my github repo of a working (first release) web app to a new directory and a new user on my computer. The web app is hosted at Heroku.

I have made some changes, push them to `origin`, and then pushed them to Heroku and the web app crashes. The changes are exceedingly minor and will not affect anything backend or complicated.

Heroku says the build was successful, there there did exist a perculiar warning:

```
###### WARNING:
       Detecting rails configuration failed
       set HEROKU_DEBUG_RAILS_RUNNER=1 to debug
###### WARNING:
       We detected that some binary dependencies required to
       use all the preview features of Active Storage are not
       present on this system.

       For more information please see:
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku
```

No idea on what and where they mean by `set HEROKU_DEBUG_RAILS_RUNNER=1 to debug`

The error logs I get during the crash are:

```
...
2019-06-01T07:14:31.564617+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/training_sessions/345" host=www.trainingrepo.com request_id=ed87114f-a296-4a84-adba-57f7249d3ea9 fwd="81.226.11.112" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2019-06-01T07:14:32.159379+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=www.trainingrepo.com request_id=990ffa88-1d6b-4e38-af9b-521b2dff6fa8 fwd="81.226.11.112" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2019-06-01T07:14:41.170353+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=www.trainingrepo.com request_id=14e1d219-30e5-4b87-96cf-3ea9378c13e1 fwd="81.226.11.112" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2019-06-01T07:14:41.642669+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=www.trainingrepo.com request_id=54ad17ed-5e6c-44ff-818a-f7e4fcd6720a fwd="81.226.11.112" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2019-06-01T07:14:44.421786+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/training_sessions/345" host=www.trainingrepo.com request_id=418bea73-f5b8-44bf-8233-6751b481d671 fwd="81.226.11.112" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2019-06-01T07:14:44.724359+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=www.trainingrepo.com request_id=a6226248-404a-4a25-8144-7bf923c362d1 fwd="81.226.11.112" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2019-06-01T07:16:15.084500+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=training-repo.herokuapp.com request_id=aeb650e9-57bb-4d60-b095-cc426a2f7a48 fwd="81.226.11.112" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-06-01T07:16:15.468246+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=training-repo.herokuapp.com request_id=17442b02-84a1-4e2d-a3d2-04f26e2bd8ef fwd="81.226.11.112" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

You'll notice that the `dyno= connect= service=` are all empty. When I rant the production check, it was a blood bath:

```
PASSED Heroku-18 Stack
FAILED Hobby Dynos
You're running on Hobby dynos. Upgrading to Standard tier dynos will provide a higher level of performance and access to important features such as metrics and faster builds. Upgrading to Performance will provide single tenant isolation for highest performance. Visit your app's resources tab to upgrade.
FAILED Dyno Redundancy
You're only running on 1 web dyno. A second dyno will provide instant fallback if one dyno fails for any reason. Scale your dynos to 2 or more on the Resources tab.
FAILED Production Postgres Database
Using a Hobby Tier Postgres database. Upgrade to a Standard or Premium Tier database for production-grade availability.
WARNING Postgres High Availability
Using a Hobby Tier Postgres database. Upgrade to a Premium Tier database for High Availability.
FAILED App monitoring
Not using an app monitoring add-on. Install a monitoring add-on such as New Relic or Librato to monitor your app's performance.
FAILED Log monitoring
No logging add-on found. Install a logging add-on such as Papertrail,or Logentriesto monitor and search your logs.
WARNING Custom Maintenance Pages
Configure customized error and maintenance pages to match your app's branding.
PASSED Heroku SSL
```

Also of note: I cannot connect to my DB locally - I am guessing it has something to do with me trying to access it from a new user account on my computer - but I am an imbecile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very hard to say what's going on without looking at your code, but this line is very telling: `Detecting rails configuration failed`. For a normal Rails app that should never happen. The other stuff in semi-optional configuration.

You could try checking if you've pushed the wrong folder level - either one step too high or low. Make sure you push the RAILS_ROOT folder - the one with the `Gemfile` in it. If you open your project on Github you should see the Gemfile listed directly in the first screen.

Comment: Thanks for your message.  I don't know what the root cause of the problem 'was' - but I suspect it had something to do with the slap-dash dev env that I set up and was pushing from.  I have since built a completely new, and carefully constructed dev env on a new computer and I am pushing fine from there.  It is noteworthy that I didn't even have a successful dev env, and had bugs trying to connect to my DB - ergo I couldn't test properly. I suspect that I broke the rails app - but again couldn't test to see what and where. But it's moot at this point.  Thanks for taking time out of your day.